# run a primitive mycouch query

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb

I'm new to couchdb and mycouch. I'm trying to implement a very simple query, I just want to get the results of a view and save it into my DTO class.

My couchdb query works, when I query it manually via HTTP:

```
http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/tshirts/_view/getAllTshirts
```

However, when I try running it from my app using mycouch, I can't get to run it. My current query:

```
using MyCouch.Requests;
using MyCouch.Responses;

// (...)

using (var client = new Client("http://localhost:5984/samples")) {
    var query = new QueryViewRequest("getAllTshirts");

    ViewQueryResponse<TShirt[]> result = await client.Views.QueryAsync<TShirt[]>(query);
    Console.WriteLine (result);
}
```

For some reason, it won't find the `Client` class. I found an example where `Client` is used on [github](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch.aspnet.identity/blob/master/src/projects/MyCouch.AspNet.Identity.Net45/MyCouchUserStore.cs), as you can see, I'm using all the `MyCouch` related namespaces as in the example.

I also tried using `MyCouchStore` instead:

```
using (var store = new MyCouchStore("http://localhost:5984/", "samples")) {
    var query = new QueryViewRequest("getAllTshirts");
    ViewQueryResponse<TShirt[]> result = await store.Views.QueryAsync<TShirt[]>(query);
    Console.WriteLine (result);
}
```

However, the `store` doesn't contain any property named `Views`.
Any ideas how to query my view using MyCouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantely, the documentation was not up to date. The constructor requires now 2 arguments, the second being an optional bootstrapper. This worked for me:

```
var client = new Client("http://localhost:5984/samples", null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do, with the MyCouchStore

```
using (var store = new MyCouchStore("http://user:password@localhost:5984", "samples")) {
    var query = new Query("tshirts", "getAllTshirts");

    var rows = store.QueryAsync<TShirt>(query).Result;
}
```